# Print hash key in Facebook SDK 3.0 if not using Single Sign On?

Tags: android, authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I'm having the problem "App is misconfigured" and I'm thinking the problem is the hash key.

I would to print for verify.

How can I show it in logcat without using Single Sign On but with LoginButton authentication?

Thanks.

I forgot to mention that I'm developing on Android.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to generate a hash key from your debug key store, and put it to your fb app config.

try to use the keytool:

keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR-ALIAS_HERE -keystore PATH_TO_YOUR_KEYSTORE -storepass KEYSTORE-PASSWORD -keypass KEY-PASSWORD | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

for android debug keystore:

**Alias**: androiddebugkey

**Both passwords**: android

Comment: I've done that and it does not work. I would check this key is correct or not print it into logcat.

Comment: well now i dont understand. how do you want to get this key in android app to print it in logcat ?

Comment: ok. I have generated the hash key with keytool yet but I'm having the problem at login ("the app * is misconfigured"). I think problem is an hash key wrong and for this, I would print it into logcat and I would help for this. Now it's ok?

Comment: i dont think there is any possibility to print hash key in logcat

Comment: Using SSO, in method onFacebookError(FacebookError error), just add Log.i("TEST", error.toString()); and it show the real hash key by insert into facebook app.

Comment: look this http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10923735/android-facebook-invalid-key-android-key-mismatch?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved!!! :D

I created a "test" project using SSO.

Linking old Facebook API it all works fine (using hash key generated with keytool) but, linking the new Facebook API 3.0.2 retrieve the error message "key mismatch".

Then, I copied the key show it in error message in dashboard and it all works!